# jquery ajax request is OPTIONS even I set crossDomain in $.ajax

Tags: javascript, django, jquery, cross-domain

here is part of my code

```
        $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '//outside.com/api/v1/userinfo.json',
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: 'json',
```

why i am still getting Options on request?

```
"OPTIONS /api/v1/userinfo.json HTTP/1.1" 301 0
```

any idea?

Comment: the Options request is a pre-flight request that checks to see if the server returns the correct headers to make a CORS request. In your console, are you seeing a lot of red text stating something about the same origin policy? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: Also, the crossDomain option is not needed since this is a cross-domain request.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301

**tl;dr:** `301` has nothing to do with [Cross Domain (CORS) requests](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), it is stating that the resource you're requesting has been moved.

Check your resource and find out where it has been moved to, then update the `url` field in your request code.

Comment: 301 is not the problem, it's django's automatic redirect

Comment: the problem is the request type is options

Comment: OK, you didn't provide that information - can you add the response header to your question?